# The method getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined for the type Context

Tags: android, android-tabhost

The error **The method getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined for the type Context** occur when i used  getSupportFragmentManager() inside my oncreateview.

Different context type reference was used to overcome this error but none of these works:

e.g. globalContext = container.getContext(); globalContext  = getActivity().getApplicationContext();

getSupportFragmentManager() can be set only in FragmentActivity. My question is if there is a way to reference getSupportFragmentManager().

My fragment.

```
    public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements
    ActionBar.TabListener {

        public HomeFragment(){}

        Context globalContext;

    @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
            globalContext = this.getActivity();

            actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();

            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = globalContext.getSupportFragmentManager(); // getting error The method getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined for the type Context }}

            mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(fm);


    }


    }

}
```

the tabhostlistner adapter.

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;

  public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
            super(fragmentManager);
        }}
```

This is my fragment activity

=====================================

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    // slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;
    private boolean isDrawerOpen = false;

    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // adding nav drawer items to array
        // Home
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        // Find People
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
        // Photos
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
        // Communities, Will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1), true, "22"));
        // Pages
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
        // What's hot, We  will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1), true, "50+"));


        // Recycle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
                ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                  if(slideOffset > .55 && !isDrawerOpen){
                        onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                        isDrawerOpen = true;
                    } else if(slideOffset < .45 && isDrawerOpen) {
                        onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                        isDrawerOpen = false;
                    }


                super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
            }



        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            displayView(0);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Slide menu item click listener
     * */
    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
    ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action bar actions click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /* *
     * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        menu.findItem(R.id.itmFavorite).setVisible(!isDrawerOpen);

        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /**
     * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
     * */
    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new FindPeopleFragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new PhotosFragment();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new CommunityFragment();
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new PagesFragment();
            break;
        case 5:
            fragment = new WhatsHotFragment();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }



}
```

Comment: HomeFragment  is enough ?

Comment: are you using `FragmentActivity`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1) Create the member variable:

```
private FragmentActivity context;
```

2) Override the onAttach method of your fragment:

```
@Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        context = (FragmentActivity) activity;
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }
```

3) Get the support FragmentManager like this:

```
FragmentManager fm = context.getSupportFragmentManager();
```

Comment: It gives me this error :: Main activity can not cast to FragmentActivity

Answer (score 2):

**In Kotlin**

```
   bottomSheetDialogFragment.show((context as FragmentActivity).supportFragmentManager,
                    bottomSheetDialogFragment.tag)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can access Fragment manager in your getView method like below

```
((Activity)context).getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
```

where context is an activity ref passed in adapter class

like

```
public ActorAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Actors> objects) 
{
    super(context, resource, objects);
    this.context = context;
}
```

so fragment manager can be accessed for ex.   FragmentManager fm = ((Activity)context).getFragmentManager();

Answer (score 1):

I am 100% sure that you are not importing the right package for the `support Fragment class`
make sure that your `Fragment import` in your `HomeFragment` look like this:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```